# XML validation of individual elements instead of the whole document

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-validation

In one of my projects, we support data entry using XML. Since the XML is an user input file, there are high chances of it being a valid XML, but having some semantic errors (such as string lengths greater than the allowed limt etc).

Currently I am using the javax.xml.validation.Validator to validate the given document but this will fail even if one element has a semantic error. What I want is to be able to skip such elements instead of skipping the whole XML.
I understand that we can set an error handler for the Validator in which I can skip such errors, but this means that I need to perform the semantic checks in my application code.

One solution that I can think of is it to parse the XSD and get the set of restrictions (such as timestamp format, length checks etc) and then while parsing the XML check these restrictions. Is there any elegant or well defined way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation you could

1. rewrite the original XSD so that it validates only what your want
2. use your own simplified schema, it could be just a properties file, element=rule, rule could be a regex, and make a custom validator. I think it would be faster than full blown XSD Validator
3. XSD is not the only XML schema language, consider Relax NG

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clearly described in the API documentation, but if you supply the validate() method with a DOMSource that wraps the element you want validated, it should validate only the subtree under that element.

I can't be 100% sure this is the way the JDK implementation of validate() works, but it's certainly how the Saxon XSD implementation interprets the spec.

If you don't want to grovel with low-level Java APIs, an easier way to validate a specific element (and its subtree) is with XQuery:

```
for $e in //a/b/c[condition=foo] return validate{$e}
```

With XQuery 3.0 you can use try/catch to handle the cases where validation fails.